Convolution preserve the boundary condition
Here, I want to know if convolution will preserve the Neumann condition or not. Suppose $K$ is a continuous function on some interval $[-L,L]$, and $u$ is some 'good enouth' function on $[0,L]$ that satisfies the Neumann boundary condition, i.e., $u'(0) = u'(L) = 0$. Define function $H$ by convolution,
$$
    H[u] (x) = \int_0^L K(x-y) u(y) dy
$$
Does $H[u]$ satisfy Neumann BC?, i.e., Does $H_x [u] (0) = H_x[u] (L) = 0$ ?
I suppose $u$ to be good enough since I actually don't know which specific condition should be imposed on $u$.
My attempt:
If we assume that the following holds: $H$ is self-adjoint and compact, i.e., $K$ is symmetric and the Hilbert-Schmidt condition $\int_0^L \int_0^L K(x-y)^2 dy dx < \infty$ holds. Suppose there exists a sequence of eigenvalue $\lambda_n$ and eigenfunction $\phi_n(x)$, we can try to expand $K$ and $u$ as
$$
K(x-y) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lambda_n \phi_n(x) \phi_n(y), \quad u(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \phi_n(x)
$$
then by substituting them into the convolution, we get
\begin{align}
H[u]_x = H \left[ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \phi_n \right]_x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \lambda_n \phi_n'
\end{align}
I have also tried some example kernel $K(x-y)$. For example, one can take the kernel to be the Green function of $-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + I$ with Neumann BC, and for this kernel, the eigenfunction is $\cos(n \pi x/L)$. So all the $\phi'(0) = \phi'(L) = 0$, hence the convolution satisfies the Neumann BC.
My question:

For general kernel, even if I expand them as series, I still could not find the connection between Neumann BC of $u$ and Neumann BC of $H[u]$.
Is there a relatively simpler way without using series expansion to prove this? Like integration by parts (I tried IBP but failed) or other tricks?
If we have to use the property of Hilbert-Schmidt theory, can we differentiate the series term by term here?  Will this introduce new convergence problems so that $u$ requires stronger conditions?


I will set $L=1$ with no loss of generality. You are assuming a filter that is invariant by translation, so generically, it will not "know" about the boundary condition so your answer is no. Take for example for $h<1$:
$$
K = \frac1{2h}1_{(-h,h)}
$$
Say you start with $u=1$, then:
$$
H[u](x) = \begin{cases}\frac{h+x}{2h} & x\leq h \\ 1 & h\leq x\leq 1-h \\ \frac{1+h-x}{2h} & 1-h\leq x\end{cases}
$$
and for continuous $u$ in general, $H[u]$ is differentiable at $0$ and $1$ with:
$$
H[u]'(0) = \frac{u(h)}{2h} \quad H[u]'(1) = -\frac{u(1-h)}{2h}
$$
so Neuman's boundary conditions are compromised.
The easiest way to amend this is to look for more general kernels: $K(x,y)$ which are not translation invariant. A simple generic class that you can construct can be motivated by going in Fourier space. You can decompose you $u$ as:
$$
u(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty u_n2\cos(\pi nx) \\
u_n = \int_0^1u(x)\cos(\pi nx)dx
$$
so a natural kernel is:
$$
\begin{align}
H[u](x) &=  \sum_{n=0}^\infty K_nu_n\cos(\pi nx) \\
&= \int_0^1dyu(y)\sum_{n=0}^\infty K_n2\cos(\pi nx)\cos(\pi ny) \\
&= \int_0^1dyu(y)\frac{k(x-y)+k(x+y)}2\\
k(\xi) &:= \sum_{n=0}^\infty k_n2\cos(\pi nx)
\end{align}
$$
In general, a kernel of the form:
$$
K(x,y) = \frac{k(x-y)+k(x+y)}2
$$
with $k$ supported on $(-1,2)$ satisfying:
$$
\forall x\in[0,1], k(x) = k(-x) = k(2-x)
$$
will preserve the Neumann boundary conditions for smooth enough $k$ (in Fourier space, $K_n$ decays fast enough).
You could have also motivated it from the method of images. Indeed, if you want $u$ to satisfy Neumann's boundary conditions, you can equivalently extend it on $\mathbb R$ by parity (now extended to $(-1,1)$) and $2$ periodicity. From this perspective, $H[u]$ will typically not be even and 2-periodic, which is why Neuman's boundary conditions are generically violated. The quick fix is to instead define:
$$
H[u](x) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}(K*u)(2n+x)+(K*u)(2n-x)
$$
which by construction is even and 2-periodic so the BC's are preserved.
This second method is equivalent to the first as:
$$
k(\xi) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}K(2n+\xi)+K(2n-\xi)
$$
which is related to the Fourier approach by the Poisson summation formula.

Function $K = \frac1{2h}1_{(-h,h)}$ is not continuous on $[-1,1]$.
